# Android: access thread from class

Tags: android, multithreading

I create a file download from web

This code works but after i go to home page , how can access to thread and this listener ?

filedownloader.java

```
public class FileDownloader {

    public static void download(final String downloadPath, final String filepath, final OnProgressDownloadListener listener) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(downloadPath);

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    //connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.connect();

                    int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();

                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }

                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[G.DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
                    int len = 0;
                    int downloadedSize = 0;
                    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        downloadedSize += len;
                        final float downloadPercent = 100.0f * (float) downloadedSize / fileSize;

                        if (listener != null) {
                            G.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    listener.onProgressDownload((int) downloadPercent);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    outputStream.close();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

onprogressdownloadlistener.java

```
public interface OnProgressDownloadListener {

    public void onProgressDownload(int percent);
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
OnProgressDownloadListener listener = new OnProgressDownloadListener() {

     @Override
     public void onProgressDownload(final int percent) {
           Log.i(percent + "%");
     }
};
FileDownloader.download(dlFile, G.DIR_APP + "/" + fileName, listener);
```

Percent return size of download

After start download and close page and go to new page , i want to go back to download page. how to access this thread and the listener ?

Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: After start download file , i go to home. but i back to download page , how can access to listener or thread for use from this ?

Comment: back to download page ? is this an activity or  a web view you are talking about here ?

Comment: Download page is MainActivity.java ( it mean in application ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Hey you can check if ***percent*** in main activity's listener object gets "100%" value then you can get you desired output.

Comment: Thanks , but i want use percent in every where

Comment: Pass you listener object everywhere and you can get Percent whenver you have passed you listener object

Comment: How pass listener object ?

Comment: You have already tried it `FileDownloader.download(dlFile, G.DIR_APP + "/" + fileName, listener); ` like this going from one activity to another you can pass it.